# Java Unexpected Programming Result

Tags: java, if-statement

I would like to write a game about who would take the last marble and I've successfully run it. But when I attempted to add some error messages to it, such as showing "Incorrect range" when the inputs are out of range, it doesn't work properly. I know the problem is due to the incorrect recognition of variable "totalNum", but how to solve it? Thanks in advance :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int pn = 1;
    System.out.print("Intial no. of marbles [10 ~ 100]: ");
    int totalNum = in.nextInt();
    int input = 0;
    int from = 1;
    int to = totalNum/2;

    if (totalNum < 10||totalNum > 100) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect range. Try again!");
        System.out.print("Intial no. of marbles [10 ~ 100]: ");
        totalNum = in.nextInt();
    }
    else {                          
        while (totalNum > 1) {
            totalNum = in.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Player" + pn + " [" + from + " ~ " + to + "]: ");
            input = in.nextInt();
            if (input < from||input > to) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect range. Try again!");
                continue;
            }
            totalNum = totalNum - input;
            System.out.println("Remaining no. of marbles: " + totalNum);
            if (pn == 1) {
                pn = 2;
            }
            else {
                pn = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Player" + pn + " takes the last marble.");      
    if (pn == 1) {
        pn = 2;
    }
    else {
        pn = 1;
    }       
    System.out.println("Player" + pn + " wins!");       
}
```

Comment: What's the issue exactly?

Comment: what does not work? How does it fail?

Comment: You need to use a loop, to repeatedly ask the user for input until they provide a valid value.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a meaningful description of a problem.  Step through this in a debugger and observe its behavior.  In what way does it differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this line in the while loop is the problem:

```
totalNum = in.nextInt();
```

It keeps trying to take the next input from the user but there isn't a second integer. Not sure what happens after that.

Also, your entire program seems to be roughly equivalent to doing

```
totalNum%2+1
```

and printing the answer.